# Cypress: We detected that the Chromium Renderer crashed

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, cypress, chromium

Currently I’m trying to execute a single test with Cypress:

I used: `cypress run`

I’m getting: `We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.`

And:

```
Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804

#FailureMessage Object:  Electron Framework            v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 16184648
```

I already tried with chrome and Electron, windows and Mac and the issue persists.
I also tried `--headless`.

The test is quite simple, I’m performing the login and checking the url change

Looking into it, I found that the browser is crashing after a couple of seconds loading the main page (after login was successful)

I double checked with other web pages and it’s working fine, so it’s related to the main page of my project.

The main page is working fine if I access it from Chrome directly.

Looks like it’s a memory issue loading the page but never see something like this before.

Node version: 14,16 
Os: Windows 11, MacOS monterrey 
Cypress: 10.7.0, 9.7